# why does this closure crash the browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a closure that looks like this:

```
(function(){

   var OutterScope = 1;

   (function RunThisLoop() {

      OutterScope++;
      console.log(OutterScope);

      setInterval(RunThisLoop, 1000);

   })();

})();
```

​**Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vMHdD/)**. The problem is that the console output seems off: it's supposed to update every second but it seems to be updating by more than one second every second and then it eventually crashes the browser. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely its running out of resources from invoking `RunThisLoop` and setting up the interval again and again and again...

You might want `setTimeout` instead or move the `setInterval` outside of `RunThisLoop`.

Comment: Yes, `setTimeout` is probably what was being looked for.  setInterval will cause exponential spawning.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you run the function, you add more scheduled interval timers. Eventually they snowball and consume all CPU resources.

This is the best way to fix it (there are almost no scenarios where `setInterval()` can be used without `clearInterval()`):

```
(function(){

   var OuterScope = 1;
   var myInterval = setInterval(RunThisLoop, 1000);

   function RunThisLoop() {

      OuterScope++;
      console.log(OuterScope);
      //stop clause 
      if (OuterScope > 10) clearInterval(myInterval);    
   };

})();​
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run RunThisLoop() a context is created to contain its local state.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
Then the recursive call to RunThisLoop() creates a new context for the local state of the new instance.
... 
Oops! Stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

It's already answered, this is just a clarification:

By using `setInterval` you schedule a new set of loops, and since you do that inside the loop it grows exponentially: For each second you double the number of calls:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 4
4. 8
5. 16
6. 32
7. 64
8. 128
9. 256
10. 512
11. 1 024
12. 2 048
13. 4 096
14. 8 192
15. 16 384
16. 32 768
17. 65 536
18. 131 072
19. 262 144
20. 524 288
21. 1 048 576
22. 2 097 152
23. 4 194 304
24. 8 388 608
25. 16 777 216
26. 33 554 432
27. 67 108 864
28. 134 217 728
29. 268 435 456
30. 536 870 912
31. 1 073 741 824
32. 2 147 483 648

Comment: Did you write them all out of your head? I usually bumble at 2^18 as it is the first one rarely used as any type of range or mask.

Comment: @AlexPakka 1-17 I know by heart, after that I need a calculator.